# Non-exported variable with the same name across multiple files causing TS2403

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm a TypeScript newb trying to write a Node.js (Node.ts?) backend, and trying to go about the basics of setting up my server. I'm using ts-node version 8.6.2 and typescript version 3.7.5, and defining validation for some domain objects in the following way (in the `ajv` style):

```
// domain_obj_1.ts:
const commonSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    foo: { type: 'string' },
  },
};

export class DomainObject1 {
...
```

```
// domain_obj_2.ts:
const commonSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    bar: { type: 'string' },
  },
};

export class DomainObject2 {
...
```

However, `ts-node-dev` is spitting out the following error:

```
error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. 
Variable 'commonSchema' must be of type '{ type: string; properties: { foo: { type: string; }; }; }',
but here has type '{ type: string; properties: { bar: { type: string; }; }; }'.
```

I can only assume Typescript is detecting a collision of these separate declarations of `commonSchema`, but they're not being exported so I'm not sure how that's happening.

There's a lot I don't yet understand about TS and its use in Node, but this is surprising behavior and I'm wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to get `ts-node-dev` to stop yelling at me, and it indicates there were at least a couple things wrong with my set-up. Hopefully this answer might provide enough breadcrumbs for someone else struggling with standing their own builds up:

1. I had `require('ts-node/register')` at the top of each of my knex migration files so I can write the code in modern ES syntax. Turns out this was probably causing a double-compilation problem which seems like has some unpredictable downstream effects.
2. It also turns out `ts-node`, which backs `ts-node-dev`, needs to explicitly be told where `tsconfig.json` file lives, either by setting the `TS_NODE_PROJECT` environment variable or passing the --project (-P) flag.

Addressing #1 seems to be sufficient to resolve the errors I was seeing, but for the sake of correctness I'm also addressing the missing config file so eventual compilation in prod is predictable.